# Factory pattern: Restrict object construction to factory

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a class `T` and a factory `TFactory` that creates objects of type `T`.
I want to make sure that only the factory is allowed to create new `T` objects.

A halfhearted solution would be to require the factory as a parameter in `T`'s constructor, for the only purpose that only somebody who at least brings a factory object can create `T`'s:

```
class T
{
    public T(TFactory Tf)
    {
        if (!(Tf is TFactory))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No factory provided");
    }
}
```

But wherever a `TFactory` is at hand, one could construct `T`'s.
Another approach would be to check via stack tracing, if the constructor call really came from within a TFactory, but this seems overkill to me.

A third apporach would be to put both `T` and TFactory in an assembly of their own, ad make `T`'s constructor `internal`. But a new project and assembly just for this purpose?

Any better idea anybody?
(Although my code is C#, this is probably a more general question)

Comment: Your third approach seems the most reasonable to me. Another option would be some form of a "secret handshake" - where the constructor expects a parameter that only the factory class knows how to generate - but that's hardly a viable solution given the fact that anything like that can be reversed engineered using a decompiler.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something very similar to your third approach: declare the factory as a inner class of `T`, and make `T`'s constructor `private`:

```
public class T {
    public class Factory {
        public T GetT() {
            return new T(); // simple implementation just for an example here
        }
    }

    private T() {}
}
```

Since `Factory` is inside `T`, it can access the private constructor, but outside code cannot. If you don't want to create a separate assembly, you could consider this approach.

Note that you could still put the factory class and `T` in two different files, with `partial` classes:

```
public partial class T {
    private T() {}
    // other stuff about T here...
}

// in another file

public partial class T {
    public class Factory {
        public T GetT() {
            return new T();
        }
        // other stuff about Factory here...
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not to have just a factory method in `T` then?

Comment: You could do that, but the OP seems to want to use a separate `TFactory` class. @Alex

Comment: A kind of "why are you doing that" - "because I can")

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class T { }

public class TFactory
{
    public T CreateT() => new TImpl();

    private class TImpl : T { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is the worst one. That behavior is absolutely unobvious and unclear to a client. Stack tracing also slows down execution. The 1st and the 2nd make sense.

If you want to have total control of instance creation put it into the type. Use a factory method. Remember, one should be reasonable when putting constraint on instance creation. E.g. the instance should be initiated with a polymorphal (virtual) method. One can't call such a method from a constructor (a very bad practice), so the method should be called after construction. For not to put that responsibility on the client, hide the constructor from one and provide a factory method.

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract void Initialize();
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected Derived() { /* ... */}

    protected override void Initialize() { /* ... */}

    public Derived CreateDerived()
    {
        var derived = new Derived();
        derived.Initialize();
        return derived;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_one should be reasonable_". Really great point! We need more Reasonability Driven Development. Regret I can't double-upvote.